# EF Core adding object nulls a navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a Drink object via DbContext, but after adding the drink using the context, the Brand property becomes null.
What could be the reason for this?

(Ignore the double _context add method, was debugging)

[image: Before adding the drink]
Before adding the drink
[image: After adding the drink]
After adding the drink

Models:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Drink : Product
{
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DrinkTag> DrinkTags { get; set; }
}


public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
}

public class DrinkTag
{
    public string DrinkId { get; set; }
    public Drink Drink { get; set; }
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Forget the navigation property, can you explain why drink.Name property changed?

Comment: @Smit I didn't notice that. These 2 screenshots were right after each other. I definitely was not changing anything via the watch list so I have no idea how it could have changed.

Comment: Can you share more code about your controller? Especially the method being called & how the DbContext is being injected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Drink model:

```
public class Drink : Product
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }

    // Navigational properties
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DrinkTag> DrinkTags { get; set; }
}
```

When you add a new Drink specify only the BrandId:

```
var myDrink = new Drink();
myDrink.BrandId = 2;
// ... and so on
```

Also, EF Core does not load the related properties automatically. So if you want the Brand loaded you need to manually do it like:

```
var data = myContext.Drinks
    .Include(p => p.Brand)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == yourId);
```

Comment: I am not loading, I am creating.

Comment: Where's your relation defined between those 2 tables?

Comment: The adding of the brand via a BrandId property works but do you know why the navigation property would be null after adding it via the context?